# await async WCF method

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asynchronous

I must be missing something obvious here. But I cant see wat I did wrong.
I have the following code:

```
var resp = await client.findItemsByCategoryAsync(request);
```

But this code give me the following compiler error:
[image]

Though it says awaitable I cannot use the await keyword. The method is provided by a WCF service (Ebay Finding API)

Comment: Read the error message. `Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'`

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code or error messages. They are extremely difficult to read. Copy and paste the text in to your question.

Comment: I feel bad for people who write error messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method containing the `await` operator must also be declared as `async`.

```
public async void YourMethodAsync()
{
     var resp = await client.findItemsByCategoryAsync(request);
}
```

The error message refers the current method, not the one you're calling await on.

Comment: Good analysis of the error message, but the op's method should return a `Task` and end with `Async`.

Comment: @StephenCleary Ending with Async is indeed a good convention, I'll edit the answer. However I'll stick to void as it is a valid return type and I don't know know what he's doing in the method. He's free to return Task or Task<T> if he needs to.